# jQuery if else .click/.dblclick

Tags: jquery, click, double-click

How do i assign events to a single element based on click or dblclick. Ive found jsfiddles but none of them are exact. Basically, an imitation of the instagram double tap to like or tap to visit is desired. I know how to bind the events, but not the logic.

Comment: What logic do you need other than binding the correct events? Put the doubleclick action in the `.dblclick()` handler, put the single click action in the `.click()` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do what you're asking by using .on() to bind "click" or "dblclick" to a specific element.

Check out this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pcostanz/nSkVU/

Essentially I'm binding some background color changes using .on() to the "click" and "dblclick" events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#singleclick").on("click", function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
    });

    $("#doubleclick").on("dblclick", function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
    });    

});
```

Comment: i was able to use the binding as a model for my circumstances.